# Exclude child and count parent in foreach in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add element at the fourth parent category. I want to exclude the child category from the result.

**Problem :** I am counting before excluding child category. I want to count after excluding child category.

```
foreach ($author_posts as $author_post ) {
    $i=0;
    foreach(get_the_category($author_post->ID) as $category) {   
        if ($category->category_parent < 1){
            if($i % 4 === 0)   { 
                $coco= 'fourth';         
            } else {
                $coco = '';
            }                      
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $i++ -> this is your counter, it is inside the child loop, so it counts children. Move it to the parent loop if you want to count parents.

Comment: Thank you but it's not changing anything.

Comment: I am not sure if $i % 4 === 0 is correct to had every "fourh" because it's adding also in the first and second